# Send Message using Pywhatkit Instantly

Tags: python, whatsapp

I am using Pywhatkit to send WhatsApp messages. However, it would be helpful if it could do it instantly rather than at a set time. Is there any alternative to Pywhatkit, or is there a solution?

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('+44xxxxxxxx', 'Test Msg.', 15, 20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does it:

```
pwk.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+44xxxxxxx", "Test msg.", 10, tab_close=True)
```

I was mising the '_instantly' after 'sendwhatmsg'